# combing a count statement to an existing query

Tags: mysql

There is an existing query

```
select first_name,last_name,email_address,name,captain_id,paid,p.player_num,league_id 
from stats_player p
left join  stats_player_team t on p.player_num=t.player_num 
left join  stats_team s on t.team_id=s.team_num 
where season_id=2 and name is not NULL 
order by league_id,s.captain_id,name,first_name;
```

I want to add this to create another column in the results:

```
select count(*) from (select * from stats_results
where season =2 and player1_num=123 group by week)as weeks_played;
```

`player1_num` is actually going to be a loop off of `t.player_num`

Question: can this be done in one single statement?

If not, how can I incorporate the new statement to output to the following table?

```
$results=mysql_query($query);
print "<table border=1>";
print "<tr><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>captain</td><td>Email?</td><td>League</td><td>Team</td><td>pay</td><td>wks played</td></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($results)){
    if($row['email_address'] != NULL ){
    $email='y';
    }
else {
    $email='n';
    }
if($row[captain_id]==$row[player_num]){ $iscapt="Captain"; }
    else{$iscapt="";}
$paid=$row[paid];
if($paid){$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#99ff33>paid</td>";}
    else {$playpaid="<td bgcolor=#ff6633>not paid</td>";}
printf ("<tr><td>%s</td><td> %s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></td><td>%s</td>%s \n</tr>", $row['first_name'],$row['last_name'],$iscapt,$email,$row['league_id'],$row['name'],$playpaid);

}
print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scalar query (it returns at most 1 row), so it can be placed on the list of SELECT expressions as a subquery.
An example:

```
select first_name,
       last_name,
       email_address,
       name,
       captain_id,
       paid,
       p.player_num,
       league_id,

       (   select count(*) from (select * from stats_results
           where season =2 and player1_num=123 group by week)as weeks_played
       ) As column_name

from stats_player p
left join  stats_player_team t on p.player_num=t.player_num 
left join  stats_team s on t.team_id=s.team_num 
where season_id=2 and name is not NULL 
order by league_id,s.captain_id,name,first_name;
```

btw, this query can be simplified into:

```
select count(distinct week) 
from stats_results
where season =2 and player1_num=123
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am stuck on how to incorporate it as a join statement based upon the  stats_results.player1_num=p.player_num.

Comment: So upon further investigation I found that the proper term is subquery. A little search for MySql Subquery and COUNT is showing a ton of stuff, hopefully will find something I can use to learn the best way of doing this

Comment: Finally got it all to work and it is as you described. I was either trying to make it harder, or I was mistyping. `(select count(distinct week) 
  from stats_results
  where season =10 and player1_num=p.player_num) as weeks`